# How do servers get client's IP and port number TCP?

Tags: java, tcp

In UDP I used:

```
InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress(); 

int port = receivePacket.getPort(); 

System.out.println ("From: " + IPAddress + ":" + port);
System.out.println ("Message: " + sentence);
```

I'm confused about TCP.  How do servers get the client's IP and port number using TCP?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Socket.getInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29) and [`Socket.getPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getPort%28%29).

Comment: how Is it possible, if i am using this function ->  int port= client.getPort();System.out.println("port:"+port); and getting port:63789, when i have server= new ServerSocket(5555);  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);

Comment: Calling `Socket.getPort()` returns the **remote** port that the other party is using on their end, not the **local** port that the calling party is using. If you want the **local** port, use [`Socket.getLocalPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getLocalPort%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

They use sockets.

Example:

```
Socket server = new ServerSocket(6666)
Socket connection = server.accept();
System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
```

Comment: thx, server received:Connection received from genuine.microsoft.com, but if i want more precisely, like from IP:xxx.xxx.x.xxx and port:5555?

Answer (score 0):

The source and destination IP address and port are present in every TCP segment or UDP datagram.